# How to register types in Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection?

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, autofac

I need to remake Autofac's `ContainerBuilder` to Microsoft DI's `IServiceCollection`. Please tell me how this line will look in MS.DI?

```
builder.RegisterType<GrpcServer>().As<GrpcServer>();
```

Comment: Something like this? `services.AddSingleton<GrpcServer, GrpcServer>();`

Comment: This is explained in the documentation - both the .NET Core *and* Autofac docs. You can integrate AutoFac with .NET Core's DI, [as shown in the Autofac docs](https://docs.autofac.org/en/v4.0.0/integration/aspnetcore.html). The code shown there is similar to the code shown in [Dependency injection in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-3.1) except for the Autofac-specific parts

Comment: BTW there's no reason to use `As` if you intend to use the type as-is

Answer (score 1):

I learned that by default RegisterType registers the type as InstancePerDependency, so on the Microsoft DI it will look like this:

```
services.AddTransient<GrpcServer>();
```